# Two questions about Python

Tags: python

```
def punctuation(x,y):
 if len(x) == 0:
     return y

 if '.' in x[0]:
     x[1] = x[1].capitalize()
     return punctuation(x[1:],y.append(x[0]))
 elif '!' in x[0]:
     x[1] = x[1].capitalize()
     return punctuation(x[1:],y.append(x[0]))
 elif '?' in x[0]:
     x[1] = x[1].capitalize()
     return punctuation(x[1:],y.append(x[1]))
 else:
     return punctuation(x[1:],x[0])


 z = ['!a','b'] 
 punctuation(z,[])
```

Hope to get  ['!a','b'] ,which means if the first item contains (!,?,.),the second one become capitalize

```
Q3_p1 = "Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): "
Q3_p2 = "Enter the number of key presses (>0): "



def enter_msg(n):
    x=raw_input(Q3_p1)
    y=raw_input(Q3_p1)
    Jay = Jay_chou(x,y)
    return Jay

 def Jay_chou(d,n):

     if d==0: return " " 
     elif d==1: return [".", ",", "?"][n%3-1]
     elif d==2: return ["a", "b", "c"][n%3-1]
     elif d==3: return ["d", "e", "f"][n%3-1]
     elif d==4: return ["g", "h", "i"][n%3-1]
     elif d==5: return ["j", "k", "l"][n%3-1]
     elif d==6: return ["m", "n", "o"][n%3-1]
     elif d==7: return ["p", "q", "r", "s"][n%4-1]
     elif d==8: return ["t", "u", "v"][n%3-1]
     else: return ["w", "x", "y", "z"][n%4-1]


 enter_msg(2)
```

i don't know why i got the error
i see this:

```
Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): 1

Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): 1

['1', '1']

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You got an indentation problem in your posted code! Please make sure that it runs in python, before posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second probelm:

you're passing  strings to `Jay_Chou()` in `Jay = Jay_chou(x,y)`, instead you should pass integers. In your case the `n%3` part actually tries to do string formatting instead of modulus operation.

`raw_input()` returns strings, you need to convert them to integers using `int()`

so you get this error:

```
In [13]: '1'%3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-39edc619f812> in <module>()
----> 1 '1'%3

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**try this:**

`Jay = Jay_chou(int(x),int(y))`

then it outputs:

```
Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): 3
Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): 4
d

#and for 1,1:

Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): 1
Enter the digit on the phone (0-9): 1
.
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i tried, but got none back....

Comment: @user1799607 please indent your code properly first.

Comment: @user1799607 it doesn't returns None, try `print enter_msg(2)`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot for all of you

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you could do something like:

```
import itertools as it
the_list = ['a!', 'b']
result = [the_list[0]]
my_iter = iter(the_list)
next(my_iter)   #my_iter.next() for python2

for i,(a,b) in enumerate(it.izip(the_list, my_iter)):
    if set('.?!').intersection(a):
        result.append(b.capitalize())
    else:
        result.append(b)
```

The problem in your code is that you call:

```
punctuation(x, y.append(something))
```

The `append` method returns `None` and thus the second argument of the recursive call has wrong type.

You must do:

```
y.append(something)
punctuation(x, y)
```

Comment: `next(obj, [default])` is valid for 2.6+

Comment: @JonClements I thought it was introduced only in python2.7+

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next

Comment: Thanks for help, but question said cant use loop

Comment: and i tried y.append(something)
punctuation(x, y), but i got a none....

Comment: it works....but i could only accept one answer?

Comment: @Konie I did not read you couldn't use loops. I'm thinking of adding a bit of explanation, if you need it.
Yes, on stackoverflow you can only accept one answer, by definition. Either an answer answers completely/enough to "solve" the problem in your question, or it's not an answer at all, in which case you should not accept it. Then you are free to use the SO tools as you wish.